# How to return a function that combines two functions with two arguments

Tags: python, function, lambda

I have two functions each taking two arguments.
The first function, `a`, prints out combined result of two arguments(integers) and the second function, `b`, prints out two arguments separated by space.

So if I execute `a(1,2)` it will print out 3 while `b(1,2)` will print out 1 2.

I tried creating a function that returns lambda as `lambda x, y : (a(x,y), b(x,y))`
but when I tried it out, it didn't print anything out.

The functions have its own `print` inside it so I guessed that when creating lambda, it should print out the result and then return a super function.

```
def a(c, d):
    print('*', a)
    return total

def b(c, d):
    print('**', b)
    return echo

def both(f, g):
    return lambda x, y: (a(x, y), b(x, y))
```

Comment: Is `both` supposed to take two functions and return a function that calls both of them, or is it supposed to take two integers and call both `a` and `b` on them? You seem to have mixed up which option you were going for.

Comment: The functions in your sample code do not do what the text says. If you post sample code it should relate to your question.

Comment: It's supposed to return and at the same time, executes them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lambda` function is never actually called. You need to save it when it's returned from the `both` function. Then, you can call it.

Here's an example:

```
super_function = both(1, 2)
super_function(1, 2)
```

There's a myriad of other errors in your logic but that will "fix" your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear what you want to do. This is how I understand it.

I've defined functions `a` and `b` as you seem to have described them.

```
def a(c, d):
    return c+d

def b(c, d):
    return '%s %s'%(c,d)
```

`class Both` retains definitions of two functions with similarly defined parameter sets. It's `__call__` method returns the results of the two functions for the same parameter list as a two-tuple.

```
class Both:
    def __init__(self, f, g):
        self.f = f
        self.g = g
    def __call__ (self, *args):
        return (self.f(*args),self.g(*args))
```

These final lines are just two slightly different ways of using the `class`.

```
both = Both(a,b); print (both(1,2))

print (Both(a,b)(3,5))
```